# The same user profile and other user icon shown twice on the log on screen of windows 7 pro

Tags: windows-7, login, domain, user

For some reason I have a machine that is showing the last user who logged in twice on the log on screen. After you hit the Ctrl-Alt-Delete command it will show the last user logged in but twice and it will also show the other user icon twice. Any ideas as to why this is happening.

Thanks.

Comment: A screenshot would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance that you have OmniPass installed?

I've found out that people (mostly with Fujitsu) had the same problem after a windows update while having that software installed.

Their solution was to uninstall and install again the OmniPass. Note that many had issues finding the installer (check at your manufacturer's website)

Read more:

- [Link 1](http://forums.majorgeeks.com/showthread.php?t=230878)
- [Link 2](http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-vista-all/65235-double-login-after-windows-update-w-vista-business-2.html)
- [Link 3](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-account-administration/84197-same-account-shows-twice-login-screen.html)